# How can I get all data from multiple <span>s with multiple tags into an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm looking for the best practice for taking multiple span tags from multiple spans and sticking them into an array (or json object) for later use. (Not even sure whether array or json is the way to go.)

Html:

```
<span class="car" id=c1 data-make="volvo" data-year="2010">Car1<span>
<span class="car" id=c2 data-make="saab" data-year="1998">Car2<span>
```

js:

```
var cars = document.getElementsByClassName('car');
for(var i=0; i<cars.length; i++) { 
  <what goes best here?>
}
```

Currently, I've created 3 flat arrays for each ID, data, and year, but that seems messy. I'm having trouble figuring out how to create:

```
    Array(
[0] => Array(
        [id] => c1 
        [make] => volvo
        [year] => 2010
    )
[1] => Array(
        [id] => c2
        [make] => SAAB  
        [year] => 1998    
    )
);
```

Or a json object:

```
jsonString = [
    {
        "id": "c1",
        "make": "volvo",
        "year": "2010",
    },
    {
        "id": "c2",
        "make": "saab",
        "year": "1998", 
    }
];
```

My need for this is simple. I will use the information to do some simple replacement of innerHTML like:

```
document.getElementById(car[id]).innerHTML = car[make]
```

So, two parts:
1) What would be better for this type of task - multi-dimensional array or json object?
2) what goes in the  section of my loop to stick the data into that array or json?

Thanks - I'm still learning.

Comment: The decision array *or* JSON does not make sense. An array is a data structure in JavaScript. You can *convert* an array *to* JSON if you want to exchange the data with an other service or persist it.

Comment: @FelixKling So JSON is really just a "package" - whereas for internal JS needs I should stick with an array? I wasn't clear about whether you could manipulate JSON easily...

Comment: JSON is a textual representation of data, just like XML, YAML, CSV and others. It's useful for exchanging data between languages / systems / etc and it is popular in combination with JavaScript because of the syntactic similarities (that's where it got its name from).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over all the attributes of each element and add each `data-` attribute to the corresponding object:

```
var result = [],
    pattern = /^data-/;

// don't access the 'length' property of a live list in each iteration,
// cache it instead
for(var i = 0, l = cars.length; i < l; i++) { 
    var element = cars[i],
        attrs = element.attributes,
        car = {};

    // setting the ID
    car.id = element.id;

    // iterating over all attributes
    for(var j = 0, jl = attrs.length; j < jl; j++) {
        var name = attrs[j].name;
        if(pattern.test(name)) { // if the attribute name starts with 'data-'
            // remove the 'data-' part and add the value to the current object
            car[name.replace(pattern, '')] = attrs[j].value;
        }
    }

    // add the object to the final list
    result.push(car);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/J2TK8/)

Comment: I like that the end result is push(car)... must be talking about the Volvo... ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use jQuery, you can use the following. Otherwise, use Felix's answer.

You should use an array of objects, like so:

```
var arr = [];
$("span").each(function(i) {
    arr[i] = {};
    arr[i]["id"] = $(this).attr("id");
    arr[i]["make"] = $(this).data("make");
    arr[i]["year"] = $(this).data("year");
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from JQuery (for both learning and lean...) but might be useful for someone else.

Comment: @Trees4theForest - Alright that's fine. As said, just use Felix's answer then (haven't tested it, but I assume it's working). I do recommend that you eventually get into jQuery, though. It's very helpful.